# Prove or disprove there is an entire function so that for every $z \in \mathbb C$, $|f(z)|=x^2+y^2+1$

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove or disprove there is an entire function so that for every $z=x+iy \in \mathbb C$, $|f(z)|=x^2+y^2+1$

This seems incorrect however I can't really think of how to refute it. $|f(z)|=|z|+1$. Maybe I can use this somehow...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there exists an entire function $f$ such that $|f(z)|=|z|^2+1$, then 
$f(z)\neq 0$. This implies that $g(z)=\frac{1}{f(z)}$ is well-defined and also an entire function. Moreover, 
$$|g(z)|=\frac{1}{|f(z)|}=\frac{1}{|z|^2+1}$$
which implies that $g$ is bounded. By Liouville's Theorem, $g$ must be constant, and $f$ is a constant function, which contradicts $|f(z)|=|z|^2+1$.

Answer (score 3):

If $f(z)$ satisfies such identity it never vanishes on $\mathbb{C}$, hence $g(z)=\frac{1}{f(z)}$ is a holomorphic *and bounded* function on $\mathbb{C}$. By Liouville's theorem, $g(z)$ is constant, hence $f(z)$ is constant, too, giving a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

It can be seen that $f(z) \neq 0$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$, hence an analytic branch of $\log f(z)$ can be defined. However, $$\Re \log f(z)=\log |f(z)|= \log(x^2+y^2+1)$$ is not harmonic, as should be expected of the real part of an analytic function.